# I dont want more than one instance of my activity

Tags: android, android-activity

My service has a notification with an intent to launch the associated activity, but I find sometimes that when pressing back in my activity it returns to a previously loaded activity, so it looks like there are sometimes where there are more than one copy of the activity in memory. How can I avoid this? I suppose I must bring to front in case exist or launch a new one but dont know exactly how.
thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In you `AndroidManifest.xml` add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` with the as attribute with the desire activity you want to run only 1 instance.

e.g

```
<activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
```

You can even use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT` 
flag with you activity intent. So that when activity is already running it will be brought to front instead of creating new.

Comment: It's more normal to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT. The one you quote is meant to be used by the system.

Answer (score 0):

Add the flag [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) to your intent